# A problem on compactness and continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness

This is a problem from Carother's chapter on Compactness.

Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,1] \times [0,1]$ be continuous and one-one. Show that $f$ cannot be onto. Moreover, show that the range of $f$ is nowhere dense in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$.

I could prove that $f$ cannot be onto. What I have not been able to prove is the "nowhere dense" part.

How do I go about solving this one?

Answer (score 3):

If $f([0,1])$ is not nowhere dense, then it has nonempty interior (since it is closed), thus it contains a closed square $S=[a,b]\times [c,d] \subseteq f([0,1])$. The inverse $f^{-1}:f([0,1]) \to [0,1]$ is continuous, hence the restriction $f^{-1}\mid_S:S \to [0,1]$ is continuous. Since $S$ is compact and connected also $f^{-1}(S)$ is compact and connected, hence $J:=f^{-1}(S)$ is a compact interval. Thus there is s a bijective continuous function from $J$ to $S$. By rescaling you can construct a bijective continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]^2$, which is impossible.